# selenium click on Accept the risk and continue

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have loaded the following `drive.page_source` using `selenium`:

```
      <div id="advancedPanelContainer">
        <div id="badCertAdvancedPanel" class="advanced-panel">
          <p id="badCertTechnicalInfo"></p>
          <a id="viewCertificate" href="javascript:void(0)">View Certificate</a>
          <div id="advancedPanelButtonContainer" class="button-container">
            <button id="advancedPanelReturnButton" class="primary" data-telemetry-id="return_button_adv">Go Back (Recommended)</button>
            <button class="primary try-again">Try Again</button>
            <div class="exceptionDialogButtonContainer">
              <button id="exceptionDialogButton" data-telemetry-id="exception_button">Accept the Risk and Continue</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to click on the button `Accept the Risk and Continue` .I tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[@id="exceptionDialogButton"]')
```

but it returns no error where the `driver.page_source` is not rendered.

An intermediate rendered page contains security certificates and security button.

How can I properly find this element ?

I tried to click the button but no success with the proposed solutions

I am trying to access this link with following `selenium` options,profile and capabilities

```
url='http://kerix-export.net/en/exporter/Banque-Centrale-Populaire_MA5000212955d58c725.html'

def selenium_profile(args):
    #
    proxy_ip,proxy_port,username,password=args
    #
    proxy={"http": "http://"+username+":"+password+"@"+str(proxy_ip)+":"+str(proxy_port),
    "https": "http://"+username+":"+password+"@"+str(proxy_ip)+":"+str(proxy_port)}
    #SELENIUM ENTRIES
    cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    cap["marionette"] = True
    cap['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
    #capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = False
    binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
    ##
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--load-images=no')
    options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
    ##
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
    #profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "[user-agent string]")
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0")
    #
    return profile,options,cap,binary
```

with the final calls:

```
profile,options,cap,binary=selenium_profile(args)
driver,options,args,df=selenium_request(profile,options,cap,binary,url,df,args)
```

I think the issue can be solved following the TLS protocol

```
<p>This website might not support the TLS 1.2 protocol, which is the minimum version supported by Firefox. Enabling TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 might allow this connection to succeed.</p>
```

Comment: If provided solution doesn't work then check if element is inside an `iframe`

Comment: "but it returns an error"... what's the error? This should always be included in the question itself.

Comment: @jeffC , no error , the desired page source is not rendered, an intermediate rendered page contains security certificates and security button if I wish to proceed

Comment: Then you need to update your question and remove that part. When you state it returns an error, people are going to expect that it actually returned an error message and for you to put that in the question.

Comment: @jeffC thanks, updated the content

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting for the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="exceptionDialogButton"]'))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not look for a harder ways if there is already element ID.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((SelectBy.ID, "exceptionDialogButton")))
driver.driver.find_element_by_id("exceptionDialogButton").click()
```

Try also `exception_button` as a locator.
Also try css selector: button[data-telemetry-id=exception_button]

It will look like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((SelectBy.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-telemetry-id=exception_button]")))
driver.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[data-telemetry-id=exception_button]").click()
```

Comment: as the proposed answer below, it returns a `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

Comment: still same error, I think the error comes from the TLS protocol which is outdated while the firefox browser is up-to-date

Comment: Is your page opened? What do you see after it is opened?