# How to retrieve the value in a class using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a number(the value of bitcoin) from a site, using this code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://it.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCEUR/?exchange=BINANCE')
el = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tabValue-HYHP1WHx')
el_value = el.get_attribute("value")
print(el)
driver.quit()
```

It should print a number, but it prints **None**. I tryed to use other modules such as .getText, but the result is always None.
What can I use to get the value I want?

I want one between the red one and the orange one:
[image]

Comment: You have to wait until the element is loaded in page before getting its attribute. That's probably why it returns None

Comment: There are 16 elements on the page that match your locator. You need to describe which element on the page you are trying to get the value from. A screenshot of the page indicating which one would be extra helpful.

Comment: I added the picture

Comment: I added locator for the red one. Thanks for the picture. Previous locator was for the orange one.

Answer (score 1):

I've found there already a solution, but might that will help as well:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://it.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCEUR/?exchange=BINANCE')
time.sleep(3)
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last']")
el_value = el.text
print(el_value)
driver.quit()
```

by webdriver type, use you preferable one

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is not unique. Try to use mine. Also you are printing element, not its value.

```
driver.get('https://it.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCEUR/?exchange=BINANCE')
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.tv-symbol-price-quote__value.js-symbol-last')
el_value = el.get_attribute("value")
print(el_value)
driver.quit()
```

If `el_value = el.get_attribute("value")` won't work, use

```
el_value = el.text
```

To wait for your element use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((SelectBy.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tv-symbol-price-quote__value.js-symbol-last")))
```

10 - number of seconds you wait.

Comment: Con questo ha funzionato, grazie mille

Comment: When I copy the CSS selector of a web object, for example the one in the question, it gives me something different from yours, and doesn't work. How do I get the correct one?

Comment: @vitaliis like css selectors, but prefer xpath more, easier and fleaxible

Comment: I updated locator. It should get that fields value.

Comment: Do not forget to use implicit/explicit wait in order for the locator to load. Look here how to use explicit wait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798778/selenium-click-on-accept-the-risk-and-continue/66802675#66802675

Comment: @Vova I like both. There are some situations where CSS locators cannot be used. But in general they are shorter and easier to maintain.

Comment: @vitaliis so do I, even better to use just ids, and sometimes css selector more shorter